# Multiple Query Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a messages table with all messages in it. I want to do a query and group by phone number while matching the phone numbers with my employee table and return the latest message/time for that phone number.

The query I'm using now gives me the first message it finds instead of the newest message. Everything else is works perfect though.

Employee Table

```
id,firstname,lastname,phonenumber,crew
```

Messages Table

```
id,type,phonenumber,message,status,date
```

Query I'm using now

```
select V.firstname,V.lastname,U.phonenumber,U.message,U.read,
    max(U.date) as last_date
from messages as U left join employees as V
    on V.phonenumber = U.phonenumber
group by U.phonenumber
order by last_date desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last message date for each phone number you can use a query like this:

```
select phonenumber, max(date) as max_date
from messages
group by phonenumber
```

to get the last message per phone number you then have to join the previous query back with the messages table:

```
select m.*
from
  messages m inner join (
    select phonenumber, max(date) as max_date
    from messages
    group by phonenumber
  ) lm on m.phonenumber = lm.phonenumber and m.date=lm.max_date
```

then you can just join with the employees table:

```
  ... inner join employees as v
  on m.phonenumber = v.phonenumber
```

Comment: I am fine with basic queries. But this was a little too confusing for me. With a couple tweaks I got your code to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Right Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp) to handle it. Just look at the [example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_right&ss=-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subselect with group by

```
select V.firstname,V.lastname,U.phonenumber,U.message,U.read, U.date
from messages as U left join employees as V
on V.phonenumber = U.phonenumber
where (U.date, U.phonenumber) in (select phonenumber, max(date) 
          from messages  group by phonenumber)
order by U.date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that may help:

```
select firstname,lastname,phonenumber from employees
left join messages
on employees.phonenumber = messages.phonenumber
where messages.date = (select max(date) from messages)
```

Examples from:
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-date.php